# Ubuntu 18.04 install on an old Intel motherboard

Tags: drivers, wireless, 18.04, dell, intel

The Ubuntu 18.04 official download website has the amd64 (64-bit) .iso file only. A 32-bit Ubuntu 18.04 .iso file is not available.

I have 2 Dell Latitude E6420 laptops with Intel motherboards. On one motherboard, the Ubuntu 18.04 installation seemed to work OK, but not on the other. Is there a download specifically for Intel motherboards, and how do I get it? Any other tips are appreciated. Specifically, in one motherboard, the one with issues, the wifi switch will not activate and the wifi will not turn on.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  What do you mean by Intel MoBos/MoBo.  The intel site doesn't have a listing.  Anyway AMD64 refers to the amd/intel  64 bit or x86_64 processors (amd was first with a 64 bit x86 cpu & all companies including microsoft call it amd64).  Intel also have a IA64 chipset, but it's not x86 compatible.  You should limit yourself to one question, and if it's about wifi - please concentrate on one issue on a single machine.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Please run the command `sudo lshw -C network` and add the results of `sudo lshw -C network` to your question.

Comment: Looks like your issue is with wifi drivers, (perhaps even faulty hardware on the problematic unit), but not CPU architecture.  A quick search shows that the Dell Latitude E6420 has an Intel Core i5-2520M processor, which runs in both 32bit and 64 bit modes. You can use the amd64 (aka x86_64) Ubuntu .iso

Answer (score 1):

- The Ubuntu 64-bit iso files with `amd64` in the file name should work in your Dell Latitude E6420 laptops. (There is no download specifically for Intel motherboards, the same iso files work for all brands of motherboards for Intel type PCs (typically with Intel and AMD processors).)

---

Even if the computer's name and model numbers are the same, there can be different hardware components inside. In this case I would guess that there are different hardware for wifi. For example, if the wifi hardware is made by Broadcom, you need a proprietary driver.

Try the following command line in order to identify the wifi hardware,

```
lspci|grep -i net
```

You can expect to see

- one line for Ethernet (wired network) and
- one line for wireless network (the brand name and model should be found here)

You should also check that the wireless hardware is turned on. See the picture.

If you find wireless hardware by Broadcom, you can get more specific information about the version of Broadcom (the model number) via the command

```
lspci -nn -d 14e4:
```

and then you can select driver from the list in the following 'AskUbuntu answer',

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395)

---

The switch for wifi on Dell Latitude E6420:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The different versions have everything to do with the CPU and nothing to do with the motherboard. The output of `lscpu | grep op-mode` will indicate whether a CPU supports 64-bit processing in which case you don't need a 32-bit ISO: Most CPUs released in the last 10 years will provide output like this:

```
lscpu | grep op-mode
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
```

If 64-bit is listed as an operating mode, simply install the standard amd64 ISO if not, you'll need to utilize a recent i386 image such as for [16.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/) It does sound however that this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and your real issue is wifi in which case [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1112428/225694) may be useful. Ideally if you want help with wifi troubleshooting you should review [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and then edit your post to provide necessary information to help you. Cheers!