# No network on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell laptop

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, dell

I did a fresh install via USB of Ubuntu 16.04 on my 2014 model [Dell Vostro 2520 laptop](https://www.flipkart.com/dell-vostro-2520-laptop-3rd-gen-ci3-4gb-500gb-ubuntu/p/itmf3s3feywa5zta?pid=COMDHJVNHHPUY9JS&lid=LSTCOMDHJVNHHPUY9JSNKSSBV).
Everything went well except there's no network. It doesn't even show the WiFi options in the network.
[image]

How do I diagnose ?

```
anjanesh@anjanesh-Vostro-2520:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for anjanesh: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c07fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: enp9s0
       version: 07
       serial: e0:db:55:aa:12:84
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

Comment: Try according to the tips at [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112337/ubuntu-18-04-install-on-an-old-intel-motherboard/1112428#1112428) and the link from it if you find Broadcom wifi hardware.

Comment: If you need an internet connection to install a new driver (or other software), please consider a wired connection (an ethernet cable to your router before you have wifi working).

Comment: Not sure if it is going to help in your case, but I found that on a different Dell laptop neither WiFi nor Ethernet was detected by Ubuntu 16.04. On Ubuntu 18.04 both works.

Comment: Yes :-) You have Broadcom hardware for wifi, and I suggest that you try according to my first comment (and its link).

Comment: @kasperd : I installed 18.10 and all works. Thanks.

Comment: @anjanesh Just keep in mind that 18.10 is not an LTS release. So you'll have to upgrade to 19.04 once it's released as well as 19.10 and 20.04. That's why I tried 18.04 first. 18.04 is an LTS release so I can keep running that version until 20.04 is out and even further if I want to.

Comment: @kasperd: I got boot error when trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 via USB, hence I downloaded 18.10. It could've been a corrupt file or something else.

Comment: @anjanesh If Ubuntu 18.10 fixes a significant problem for you then it is of course worthwhile with the extra upgrade cycles.

Comment: @kasperd I have the latest LAMP stack on 18.10 - I don't think I would upgrade Ubuntu to a newer version on this laptop any more as the hardware is of 2011 (It came with Ubuntu 12.04 pre-installed).

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Dells used broadcom wireless cards.  I'm not sure about your model.  But you should be able to find out by typing `inxi -Nn` in a terminal.  If it is broadcom then you'll need to add the correct driver depending upon the chipset used.
See here for more info: [Broadcom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Ok can you get a Ethernet (hard) connection?  If so install `bcmwl-kernel-source` if you can not get it on line you can still install it from the live usb stick you used to install with by going to pool>main>g>glibc
Install glibc-dev-bin fist (use gdebi) Then install libc6-dev after those are install go to pool>restricted>b and install bcmwl-kernel-source.
good luck. after that wifi should work.

Comment: inxi is not installed and I can't install it.

Comment: you can use this command then: sudo lshw -C network

Comment: I've edited my question by adding the output of lshw -C network